# Mule choice compare

Tags: mule

In mule flow I need to compare the last two params from an input string message

> 2012-04-30,2012-05-30,1,5

And if `param1(1) <= param2(5)`, I need perform `jms:outbound-endpoint`.

Is there a standard choice element to do it? Could you please provide example.

Comment: which version of mule are you using?

Comment: @genjosanzo I have used version="CE-3.2.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using mule 3.2.x your best option is to use the groovy evaluator and use a choice router that look like the following

```
 <when expression="#[groovy:payload.split(',')[2] &lt;= payload.split(',')[3] ]">
      <processor-chain>
          <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="out" doc:name="JMS"/>
      </processor-chain>
 </when>
```

Otherwise if you are willing to upgrade to Mule 3.3.0 you can take advantage of the new [Mule Expression Language](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Expression+Language) that allows to do the same without the need of the groovy operator

Answer (score 0):

you can also use splitter and split on the basis of ',' and then have the compare logic for the params

Comment: Show some examples so people can easily understand

Answer (score 0):

You need not use Groovy for this. You can directly apply the split() function on payload.

```
<when expression="#[payload.split(',')[2]&lt;=payload.split(',')[3]]">
  <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
     <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="data" connector-ref="Active_MQ"doc:name="JMS"/>
  </processor-chain>
</when>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from expression filter you can also use choice flow control. Capture the 2 values to be compared in a flowvars and use below expression in when condition of choice flow control.

## [flowVars.param1 <= flowVars.param1]

Giving below the link for more information.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/choice-flow-control-reference

Answer (score -1):

you can take advantage of the new Mule Expression Language that allows to do the same without the need of the groovy operator